# SQL can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql

I already created the rest of the tables but it doesn't stop, I ask for help

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cun`.`factura` (
  `id_factura` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tipodepago` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_envio` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_factura`),
  INDEX `fk_formadepago_idx` (`id_tipodepago` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_clientes_idx` (`id_cliente` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_envio_idx` (`id_envio` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_formadepago`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipodepago`)
    REFERENCES `cun`.`formadepago` (`id_tipodepago`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_detallefactura`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_factura`)
    REFERENCES `cun`.`detalle_factura` (`id_factura`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_cliente`)
    REFERENCES `cun`.`clientes` (`id_cliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_envio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_envio`)
    REFERENCES `cun`.`envio` (`id_envio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Comment: If you want to post a question in Spanish or receive an answer in Spanish please post on [es.so] instead.

Comment: What error are you getting?